# GetTickCount / Sleep not working? or is it a GetTickCount precision issue?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, sleep, gettickcount

Checkout the below code:

```
tick1 = GetTickCount();
Sleep (100);
tick2 = GetTickCount ();
```

The tick2-tick1 most of times comes less than 100. My expectation is it should always 100+. Is my expectation wrong?

Comment: How far "less"? GetTickCount() is having a limited resolution of usually 10..16ms (according to MSDN).

Comment: yes, the diff comes around 94, 92.. What does limited resolution means?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like yours (and mine) expectations ARE wrong.

I used better timing:

```
chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> tick1, tick2;
std::chrono::milliseconds timespan(100); // or whatever
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    tick1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    Sleep(100);
    tick2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = tick2 - tick1;
    cout << elapsed_seconds.count() << endl;
}
```

The majority of intervals are 0.099XXX with 2 or 3 (out of 100) 0.1000XXX

The std::this_thread::sleep_for(...) recommended in 
[Precise thread sleep needed. Max 1ms error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397571/precise-thread-sleep-needed-max-1ms-error) has similar results.
But the error is less than 1ms. Do you need better precision?

Comment: I would like to respectfully request an explanation for the downvote.

The original question was: "Is my expectation wrong?", and I think we established that Sleep(100) can sleep for less than 100ms.