# Busy spinning instead of sleep for time critical situations

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I stumbled across a problem which invokes some time critical functionalities. My thread has to perform some actions and then sleep for **exactly** 60ms. Since required platform is Windows (language C++) and I know it really has a problems with time measurements like this I got an idea to increase accuracy of thread sleep.

Instead of:

```
void run() {
    do_some_action();
    sleep(60); // ms
}
```

I wanted to make it like this:

```
void run() {
    do_some_action();
    curr_time = get_time_in_nanosec(); // with QueryPerformanceFrequency/QueryPerformanceCounter
    while(get_time_in_nanosec() - curr_time < 60000000 /*60ms*/) {}
}
```

Is it worth additional CPU usage and how could I measure performance (is it sleeping correctly)?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? There may be better solutions if we have more information.

Comment: @const_ref Just need a thread to sleep for 60ms (as precisely as possible).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Precise thread sleep needed. Max 1ms error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397571/precise-thread-sleep-needed-max-1ms-error)

Comment: This is "not nice". What if I also want *my* program to have an exact wait and add another loop? What happens when all cores are taken?

Comment: The only way to be sure it to not use Windows, (or Linux, or any other desktop OS).  You need dedicated hardware.

Comment: Also 'exactly 60ms' is not realisable in any scenarion.  You can get really close with, say a hydrogen fountain maser clock, but it's a bit expensive.  You need to supply limits, eg. '60ms +- 1ms'

Comment: what exactly does _"**exactly** 60ms"_ mean? Can you provide tolerances?